# Retrive value from PHP foreach array with stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

```
Array (
      [0] => stdClass Object
                             (
                               [object_id] => 109957
                              )
      [1] => stdClass Object 
                              (
                                [object_id] => 109834
                               )
      [2] => stdClass Object
                              ( 
                                [object_id] => 109952 
                              )
      [3] => stdClass Object
                            ( 
                              [object_id] => 109964
                                )

 )
```

Comment: What is your question? Just an array???

Comment: neither heading nor question is clear !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($some_array as $key => $row) {
  $row->object_id; // Get object id
}
```